# Plotting timeseries charts in Highcharts not in plotting order of chart

Tags: highcharts

I am having problem in plotting the timeseries chart in highcharts
 exmaple

```
            12/05/2012  - 100
            12/01/2012  - 200    
        12/15/2012  - 300   
            11/01/2012  - 400
```

when i plot chart its order of printing is based on order of data points
but i want to plot the data time wise i.e 11/01/2012,12/01/2012,12/05/2012,12/15/2012

While plotting th chart its gets printed in zig zag manner instaed of trend line.
http://jsfiddle.net/vG8QM/

Comment: Just sort the data. If you fetch the data from a database you should sort it in that step.

Answer (score 1):

Time based data needs to be in chronological order starting from earliest date.

Comment: Please look at my [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983248/need-help-in-plotting-a-chart-using-highcharts-in-angularjs)