# Need help in plotting a chart using highcharts in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, momentjs

I have some data which is coming from elasticsearch which has **task's start** & **end time** for a particular **agent's** `task` which needs to be plotted on chart horizontally indicating start and endtime of that particular task. I tried with `columnrange` chart type but in that I was not able to get `to` and `from` range selector, [see here an example](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/1ycuwuuw/).

Then again I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/bx2000cb/2/) and I was able to get it working, but need help in plotting the Elasticsearch data in highcharts.

One other problem is that the date which I get from server is in a human readable dateformat (check `start_time` and `end_time`), EST timezone and needs to be converted to a format which can be consumed by highcharts. Please help.

My highcharts directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('operationalhighstackstock', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : true,
        link : function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('operationHighChartsData', function(values){
                new Highcharts.StockChart(values);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My template

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <operationalhighstackstock></operationalhighstackstock>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

My controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('OperationReportChartController', function($scope, $filter, $location, $transition, MyService, $timeout) {

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.isOperationalReport = true;            
        $scope.initOperationalReport();
    }

    $scope.initOperationalReport = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.isChartDataAvailable = true;
        $scope.operationReportDefaultQuery = operationReportDefaultQuery;
        $scope.operationHighChartsData = {
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container',
                alignTicks : false
            }
        }; 

        $scope.operationalReportDefaultServiceRequests();
    }

    $scope.serviceRequests = function() {
        //Common service requests if any
    }

    $scope.operationalReportDefaultServiceRequests = function() {
        $scope.isOperationalReport = true;
        MyService.getOperationalReportChartData($scope.operationReportDefaultQuery).then(function(result) {
            renderOperationalHighCharts(result);
        });
    }

    function renderOperationalHighCharts(result) {
        //var xAxisCategories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        //var series = getOperationReportChartSeriesData(result);
        var chart_options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    tickInterval: 1,
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            if (tasks[this.value]) {
                                return tasks[this.value].name;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    startOnTick: false,
                    endOnTick: false,
                    minPadding: 1,
                    maxPadding: 1
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        lineWidth: 9,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            align: 'left',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: series
        };
        $scope.operationHighChartsData = chart_options;
    }
    $scope.init();
});
```

Partly complete data which needs to be consumed by Highcharts showing tasks start and end time for a particular agent.

```
{
   "took": 43,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 29,
      "max_score": 1
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "agent_names": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "LUME - US AGG",
               "doc_count": 4,
               "top-sites": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0I00000000007W",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 2,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216934321",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T11:12:49.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T11:12:41.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "234218016",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T11:12:49.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T11:12:41.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0I00000000007X",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 2,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216556106",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T11:04:33.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T11:04:28.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "234218026",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T11:04:33.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T11:04:28.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0I00000000007Y",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 2,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "235761199",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T10:59:44.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T10:59:43.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "217265041",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T10:59:44.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T10:59:43.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0G00000000006K",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 1,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "234732452",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T10:52:59.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T10:52:59.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "USWF - 01D",
               "doc_count": 8,
               "top-sites": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0I00000000007T",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 3,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216603056",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T11:03:01.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T11:02:41.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216957850",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T07:52:12.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T07:52:01.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216839441",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T08:08:10.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T08:08:02.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0G00000000006M",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 2,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216839440",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T11:01:12.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T11:01:08.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216603055",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T10:55:23.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T10:55:22.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0G00000000006K",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 1,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216981636",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T10:52:59.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T10:52:59.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0G00000000006L",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 1,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216650284",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T10:49:06.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T10:49:06.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0G00000000006N",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 1,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216768388",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T11:05:03.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T11:05:02.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "000AAA0I00000000007N",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "top_tags_hits": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 1,
                              "max_score": 1,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "asta_sync",
                                    "_type": "tasks_run_history",
                                    "_id": "216981635",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "end_time": "2014-11-20T11:03:55.000-08:00",
                                       "start_time": "2014-11-20T11:03:43.000-08:00"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is my [plunker link with angularjs](http://plnkr.co/edit/JOKoT5?p=preview)

[Updating in progress plunker link with data mapping with Highcharts](http://plnkr.co/edit/t12uKs?p=preview)

Updating mapping code

```
var getOperationReportChartSeriesData = function(result) {
    var series = {};
    if (result != null && result != undefined) {
        var bucket = result.aggregations[AGENT_NAMES].buckets;
        bucket.forEach(function(item) {

            var agentSeries = [], agentData = {}, opTaskIdBucket = item["top-sites"].buckets;
            opTaskIdBucket.forEach(function(taskidEntry) {
                var intervalBucket = taskidEntry["top_tags_hits"]["hits"]["hits"],
                    intervalArr = [], opTaskidObj = {};
                opTaskidObj["name"] = taskidEntry["key"];
                intervalBucket.forEach(function(intervalEntry) {
                    var intervalObj = {}, start_temp = intervalEntry["_source"].start_time, end_temp = intervalEntry["_source"].end_time;
                    var st = new Date(moment(start_temp).valueOf()).getTime();
                    var et = new Date(moment(end_temp).valueOf()).getTime();

                    intervalObj["to"] = et;
                    intervalObj["from"] = st;
                    intervalObj["x"] = st;
                    intervalObj["y"] = 1;
                    intervalArr.push(intervalObj);
                })
                opTaskidObj["data"] = intervalArr;
                agentSeries.push(opTaskidObj);
            })

            series[item["key"]] = agentSeries;
        })
    } else 
        console.log("Result is "+result);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(series));
    console.log(series);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(series[0]["LUME - US AGG"]));
    return series;
}
```

**Update**

Sorry for all the confusion. To make it simple given a **json response** (given above) a **function** (getOperationReportChartSeriesData()) will prepare data in such a way that Highcharts will show individual tasks and it's run history in a horizontal bar, where x axis is the **date time** (including hours and minutes) and y axis is **tasks**. Similar to the screenshot provided below.

Below is a screenshot which is expected result.
[image]

[click here for the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/bx2000cb/2/)

**Updated with a jsfiddle** link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/JnGVh/60/)
but in this I also need [StockChart navigation & range selectors](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/columnrange).

@Pawel Fus: Thanks a lot for bearing with me. Here is the end result for anyone who faces similar problems.

[Working plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lK9921?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused with your requirements (still).

Highcharts, requires timestamps (in ms) to render. So you need to preprocess your dates, for example: `new Date("2014-11-20T11:03:55.000-08:00").getTime()` to get UTC timestamp. Now, when you have UTC times, you can use `moment.js` as suggested above to render data in specific timezone.

To use `moment.js` with Highcharts, you can extend `getTimezoneOffset` option (experimental), this way:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        /**
         * Use moment-timezone.js to return the timezone offset for individual 
         * timestamps, used in the X axis labels and the tooltip header.
         */
        getTimezoneOffset: function (timestamp) {
            var zone = 'Europe/Oslo',
                timezoneOffset = moment.tz.zone(zone).parse(timestamp);

            return timezoneOffset;
        }
    }
});
```

And live example: http://jsfiddle.net/k96t1dy7/3/

Note: your second plunker doesn't work..

Note2: Above test case is using github version of Highcharts. It's candidate version for Highcharts 4.1.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. To make it simple given a **json response** (mentioned in my question) a **function** (getOperationReportChartSeriesData()) will prepare data in such a way that Highcharts will show individual tasks and it's run history in a horizontal bar, where x axis is the **date time** and y axis is **tasks**. Similar to the screenshot provided in my question.

Comment: So you need to write parser from your data to format required by Highcharts? Why you can't do it?

Comment: I prepared the data format following [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/1ycuwuuw/) (please check `getOperationReportChartSeriesData()` function ) but I am not getting chart to show the data.

Comment: I get `Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute width="-694737840"` and `Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15` errors. Not sure what needs to be sorted and from where is the negative value coming

Comment: Updated my question with proper chart [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/JnGVh/60/). The only thing that is missing now is navigation, range selections as shown in the screenshot from my question and somehow `tasks` is showing only 2, but actually it should show 4

Comment: I see 6 tasks in your last example. The problem with missing navigation is that you are using Highcharts, not Highcharts (replace urls and in #71 line add StockChart constructor), see fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JnGVh/62/ Now as you can see, inverted option isn't supported anyway in Highstock, so you can't use columnrange series. Instead use line series, just like one of your demos: http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/bx2000cb/2/

Comment: oh! but when using line series in [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/bx2000cb/2/) I am unable to get task run `duration`, please suggest me a way to prepare data so that tooltip shows `from` & `to` of each `task`.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bx2000cb/4/ ? Just use `tooltip.formatter` so you can create string which will be later used in tooltip.

Comment: I used your [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bx2000cb/4/) and only modified the data. In this data, I have 4 **tasks** but the graph shows me only 3 and bar is displayed only for 2 of them, also hovering on left part of a task displays tooltip on right side.. Please help [http://jsfiddle.net/bx2000cb/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/bx2000cb/6/)

Comment: Why didn't you just replaced tasks variable with your own and let Highcharts converted prepare proper format? This is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/bx2000cb/7/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69298/discussion-between-abi1964-and-pawel-fus).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to parse your date object, that Highchart can consume? You can use the library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am already using momentjs to convert my date `var st = new Date(moment(start_temp).valueOf()).getTime();` under `getOperationReportChartSeriesData` function. I am even getting some bars but looks like the difference is very low.. in seconds so the bar is almost invisible.. Trying to fix the same now.

Comment: In my local system I am able to get some data but it is not visible since there are many tasks and difference between 1 of their run time is very low (in seconds) so the bar is almost invisible. I tried giving rangeSelectors default value to 1 hour but still it is not getting displayed properly. Also my plunker might have some library issues so it is not the exact result as my local systems.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve. Btw you are using getTime from the dateObject, what are you interested in? The hours, min.? Because with moment.js, you can get the hours or min. like this: momentObj.get("hour"), this will make sure you will get the hours. Look at the docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I updated my question with an image showing exactly what i want. By default range should be an hour.